# setup.py build that doesn't reinvoke compiler on every C source file / incremental build

Tags: python, setuptools

Is there a way to run `python setup.py build` with C extensions which doesn't involve unconditionally rerunning the compiler on every C file known to the Python project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have managed to integrate [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) into the our setup.py.
https://github.com/onnx/onnx/commit/d1bfcebd9c21a836d88b63ea8715c7a5b137ef32

It creates ninja build files on the fly and invoke ninja at the link stage.

Comment: You should link to a particular commit, otherwise the line number in the link will drift.